# How to find issue that causes a source generator compile exception?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, sourcegenerators

I'm developing a blazor wasm c#7 application and have hit a number of build exceptions that all state there is an issue with some sourcegenerator files that I can't find on my filesystem.

`/MyApp_wasm/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator/Pages_Browse_Components_MyApp_razor.g.cs(250,14): error CS1002: ; expected [/MyApp_wasm/MyApp.csproj]`

The associated source file doesn't have any compile issues so I'm a bit lost with regards finding the bug to perform the fix.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the Myapp.razor file?

Comment: I just wanted to see the files to resolve the issue myself - its sorted now, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the csproj file, add

```
 <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
```

to the first propertygroup.

Build and find the files under `...\obj\debug\net7\generated`.

Find the error in the .razor.g.cs file and then fix it in the corresponding .razor file.